# Best practices for implementing a thread to do fast, bulk, and continuous reading in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, usb, hid

How should the reading of bulk data from a device in C# be handled in .NET 4.0? Specifically I need to read quickly from a USB HID device that emits reports over 26 packets where order must be preserved.

I've tried doing this in a BackgroundWorker thread. It reads one packet from the device at a time, and process it, before reading more. This gives reasonably good response times, but it is liable to lose a packet here and there, and the overhead costs of a single packet read adds up.

```
while (!( sender as BackgroundWorker ).CancellationPending) {
       //read a single packet
       //check for header or footer
       //process packet data
    }
}
```

What is the best practice in C# for reading a device like this?

---

Background:

My USB HID device continuously reports a large amount of data. The data is split over 26 packets and I must preserver the order. Unfortunately the device only marks the first the last packets in each report, so I need to be able to catch every other packet in between.

Comment: What version of .net? Answer will depend on it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm targeting .NET 4.0, but it would be awesome if an answer explains the difference with other versions, too.

Comment: HID data rates are very low, 8 KB/sec at most.  You can't write code that cannot keep up with that, no "best practice" is required.

Comment: @HansPassant It's a wee bit higher than that at 64 bytes per ms, but the question isn't necessary to do with USB or HID. I'm just curious about how something like this should be handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For .Net 4 you can use a [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to provide a threadsafe queue that can be used by a producer and a consumer. The [`BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method provides an enumerator which automatically terminates when the queue has been marked as completed using [`CompleteAdding()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is empty.

Here's some sample code. The payload is an array of ints in this example, but of course you would use whatever data type you need.

Note that for your specific example, you can use [the overload of `GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts an argument of type [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var queue = new BlockingCollection<int[]>();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => produce(queue));

            consume(queue);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        }

        private static void consume(BlockingCollection<int[]> queue)
        {
            foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consuming " + item[0]);
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
        }

        private static void produce(BlockingCollection<int[]> queue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Producing " + i);
                var payload = new int[100];
                payload[0] = i;
                queue.Add(payload);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            queue.CompleteAdding();
        }
    }
}
```

For .Net 4.5 and later, you could use the higher-level classes from [Microsoft's Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has a wealth of functionality (and can be somewhat daunting at first sight).

Here's the same example using TPL DataFlow:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var queue = new BufferBlock<int[]>();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => produce(queue));
            consume(queue).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        }

        private static async Task consume(BufferBlock<int[]> queue)
        {
            while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
            {
                var payload = await queue.ReceiveAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Consuming " + payload[0]);
                await Task.Delay(25);
            }
        }

        private static void produce(BufferBlock<int[]> queue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Producing " + i);
                var payload = new int[100];
                payload[0] = i;
                queue.Post(payload);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            queue.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post a very similar answer, the only thing I had different was I had my `produce` and `consume` take in a `CancellationToken` so I could recreate the behavior of the OP's `(!( sender as BackgroundWorker ).CancellationPending)`

Comment: I put enough work in to it, I decided to post my answer anyway.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for posting an example for 4.5 too.

Answer (score 4):

If missing packets is a concern do not do your processing and your reading on the same thread. Starting with .NET 4.0 they added the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace which makes this very easy to do. All you need is a [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.100).aspx) which behaves as a queue for your incoming packets.

```
BlockingCollection<Packet> _queuedPackets = new BlockingCollection<Packet>(new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>());

void readingBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!( sender as BackgroundWorker ).CancellationPending) 
    {
       Packet packet = GetPacket();
       _queuedPackets.Add(packet);
    }        
    _queuedPackets.CompleteAdding();
}

void processingBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<Packet> report = new List<Packet>();
    foreach(var packet in _queuedPackets.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        report.Add(packet);
        if(packet.IsLastPacket)
        {
            ProcessReport(report);
            report = new List<Packet>();
        }
    }
}
```

What will happen is while `_queuedPackets` is empty `_queuedPackets.GetConsumingEnumerable()` will block the thread not consuming any resources. As soon as a packet arrives it will unblock and do the next iteration of the foreach.

When you call `_queuedPackets.CompleteAdding();` the foreach on your processing thread will run till the collection is empty then exit the foreach loop. If you don't want it to "finish up the queue" when you cancel you can easily change it up to quit early. I also am going to switch to using Tasks instead of Background workers because it makes the passing in parameters much easier to do.

```
void ReadingLoop(BlockingCollection<Packet> queue, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) 
    {
       Packet packet = GetPacket();
       queue.Add(packet);
    }        
    queue.CompleteAdding();
}

void ProcessingLoop(BlockingCollection<Packet> queue, CancellationToken token)
{
    List<Packet> report = new List<Packet>();

    try
    {
        foreach(var packet in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
        {
            report.Add(packet);
            if(packet.IsLastPacket)
            {
                ProcessReport(report);
                report = new List<Packet>();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //Do nothing, we don't care that it happened.
    }
}

//This would replace your backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() calls;
private void StartUpLoops()
{
    var queue = new BlockingCollection<Packet>(new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>());    
    var cancelRead = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancelProcess = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadingLoop(queue, cancelRead.Token));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessingLoop(queue, cancelProcess.Token));

    //You can stop each loop indpendantly by calling cancelRead.Cancel() or cancelProcess.Cancel()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for deciding to post this, it is very informative +1